# Is there way to delete a map object by the index value? Similar to Map.prototype.delete()

Tags: typescript

In my Angular 6 project I have a map to store some values. In the document I'm looping through this map by using a key-value pipe. This works fine. What I need to know is when a user clicks on an item, then I need to know how I can remove every subsequent item after that index? Is there a way to delete by index value?

I tried `Map.prototype.clear()` and `Map.prototype.delete(key)`. But I need to delete by the index, not the key.

```
<div *ngFor="let prod of this.wrapperMap | keyvalue; let i = index;">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page" (click)="selectProductObject(prod.value, i)">{{this.master.productsMap.get(prod.key)['productName']}}</li>
</div>
```

Let's say we have four items in the map and a user clicks on the 1st index. Then we need to remove every index after index 1.

Comment: There is no such a thing as "index 1" in a map. If you want to keep them in order - use some other data structure to maintain it for you (eg. an array).

Answer (score 0):

We can think in next key in the map instead of next index (index + 1):

```
function deleteNextKey<K, V>(map: Map<K, V>, key: K): boolean {
  const nextKey = getNextKey(map, key);
  return nextKey.hasValue && map.delete(nextKey.value);
}

function getNextKey<K, V>(map: Map<K, V>, key: K): { hasValue: true, value: K } | { hasValue: false } {
  const keys = [...map.keys()];
  const index = keys.findIndex(x => x === key);
  return index >= 0 && index < keys.length - 1
    ? { hasValue: true, value: keys[index + 1] }
    : { hasValue: false };
}

const map = new Map<string, string>([
  ['A', 'Item A'],
  ['B', 'Item B'],
]);

console.log(deleteNextKey(map, 'Z'), JSON.stringify([...map.entries()])); // false "[["A","Item A"],["B","Item B"]]"
console.log(deleteNextKey(map, 'B'), JSON.stringify([...map.entries()])); // false "[["A","Item A"],["B","Item B"]]"
console.log(deleteNextKey(map, 'A'), JSON.stringify([...map.entries()])); // true "[["A","Item A"]]"
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEwKYBtVVQOVQDygGlUBPAHiIBpEA1APgAoBbAQwAcAuRAWQ8poMaAazLciASm4AjOHEyskAbwBQiRBAQBnKIjAFiZRAF5EAcyx5CJUiw4iyEgNxrEAJywg3SfdbIA6AAtWLVpWdBBURAAyaMQ2dn80TGxGX0NSfwA3cMjnFQBfFRVQSFgEc0sDGwE6JgTuPnZaoURRUnEpRCVEYNDc1G4oN0iaHIjBxCJEAsQAH27ekLCJ7mBwrSjZ1XVNMB02si0TRABtfwuE-3atRgkAXRdd7V0YMDR8E5v-YDfkAEl3gRGJ9jPREKDjKZ2vl1B4oF4kH8CIh6KYAAwxOLIz7kQ6kLT+TBgMxQQKIAC0iAAjK51AB+RZ9FaRIYjVBjAbcG6nHGIADUNPuMzpiG4PWZXMQ63QmxmLiKKj2BwSJ30AHdePwdG43mYaDq9UxTq5TgByACCZpoZv+2GYiCt9yoprNACFrYhbfbEB7nSp7vkldp5KgiXAzIxklhcNUyHZ2DaAFpmiQ0ABSAGUAPI4fyGkkwYC2c6XDj+VBgYYwVC3B4SZyIAD0TelGyiACJTqcOxaO1QO3bUA6+86e27+4OfRP7vcO8H9qHw5Ho9grBkEzaPWnEFnc-nq4Xi4xS-4rpXq7W7oHGy227LO93e5OhyOO2OOxOB6-fe+5wutCXdAIyjDAY3XGxNy9K0dz3PMCzMIsSwuM9ywvXUr3rW9W2GSJEC7Hs+2-H1R3-IA)